# Log data, not only string (Python)

Tags: python, logging

I want to log data, not just string in a python.

I would like to avoid implementing this myself, since I think this was done before.

I read the [Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#using-arbitrary-objects-as-messages), but it does not cover this topic

Same here: [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html)

I want to support these primitive data types:

- strings
- integers
- datetime
- lists
- dictionaries

After logging I want to parse the log back to data again ...

Comment: why can't you just log as `"your log string" + str(whatever_value_you_have)`

Comment: I still don't understand why questions concerning "which library to use" are are not allowed here. I "moved" the question to this page: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/49402/log-data-not-only-string-python

Answer (score 5):

The `logging` module already supports this, as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#using-arbitrary-objects-as-messages) you already linked to:

```
import logging
import datetime

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

    s = "test"
    i = 5
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    l = [1, 2, 3, 4, "5"]
    d = {1:2, "a": 5}

    logging.debug(s)
    logging.info(i)
    logging.warning(today)
    logging.error(l)
    logging.fatal(d)
```

Output:

```
DEBUG:root:test
INFO:root:5
WARNING:root:2018-03-29 11:54:14.408168
ERROR:root:[1, 2, 3, 4, '5']
CRITICAL:root:{1: 2, 'a': 5}
```

If you need mixed strings and objects, use the formatting abilities (using `%` formatting by default):

```
logging.info("i = %s; s = %s", i, s)
# INFO:root:i = 5; s = test
```

Note that the logging module is clever. If you do `logging.debug("%s" % , obj)`, the `__str__` method of `obj` will always be called, but if you do either `logging.debug(obj)` or `logging.debug("%s", obj)`, it will only be called if the logging level is set to show debugging output. This saves some time, especially if this method is expensive.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use any explicit library, you may simply type-cast any object to `str` and concatenate it's value to your log string. For example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> 'My String: ' + str(datetime.now())
'My String: 2018-03-29 15:32:35.487581'
```

Personally I use `str.format` method for such tasks. It internall makes a call to `__str__` function while filling the values.

Firstly create a `dict` with the keys you want to log. For example:

```
log_data = {
    'string': '**some string**',
    'dict': {'some': 'dict'},
    'list': ['some', 'list'],
    'tuple': ('some', 'tuple'),
    'int': 1234,
    'datetime': datetime.now()
}
```

Now use unpacked version of the above dict with the `string.format` function on your string as:

```
>>> my_log_string = 'My String - {string}, My Dict - {dict}, My List - {list}, My Tuple - {tuple}, My int - {int}, My Datetime - {datetime}'

>>> my_log_string.format(**log_data)
"My String - **some string**, My Dict - {'some': 'dict'}, My List - ['some', 'list'], My Tuple - ('some', 'tuple'), My int - 1234, My Datetime - 2018-03-29 15:28:37.474416"
```

Comment: Using the built-in methods of the `logging` module has the advantage that the string will not be formatted if it is below the logging level. This saves some time for objects for which `__str__` is expensive.